# How to mock a streaming API with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, twitter-streaming-api, tweetstream

I'm playing around with the [tweetstream gem](https://github.com/tweetstream/tweetstream), which simplifies interaction with the [Twitter streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview).  I'm streaming all tweets just like the code example shown on the gem's page:

```
TweetStream::Client.new.sample do |status|
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

I've put this in a `#capture` method with some simple logic to run the stream for only a few seconds and capture all the tweets (the `status.text` strings) in an array.

I want to write unit tests for `#capture`.  How would I stub out the stream of tweets?  I'm guessing I'll have store tweets in either a file or a `StringIO` object, but I don't know how to write the mock to handle whatever TCP interaction is going on with the streaming API. I'm not sure if I should use VCR here, either.

Answer (score 0):

Read the article for a very simple way to test External services using the VCR gem
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests

Lot of people might suggest using this method below, its incomplete and brittle so best to avoid it.

```
 client = Twitter::Client.new
 client.stub(:sample).and_yield(:message)
```